# Illustrator - transform panel in pt

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

Ok, a bit of a noob question this but it's sending me a little crazy. How do I change the transform panel measurements from pt (which appears to be the default on my Illustrator CC) to px?! I've gone into preferences > units etc and the panel is still displaying **pt** not **px**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Check under File > Document Setup and change from **points** to **pixels**:

[image]

Comment: @user52229 I get it this solved your problem? If so, can you please accept the answer as the correct one? (the check mark on the left). Thank you and you're welcome !

Comment: If you have the Rulers set to On, you can just right-click on the ruler itself > pixels (or whatever system you prefer) and it should affect everything else.

Comment: Thank you so much! Illustrator is the most maddening program, I swear